# Passing a variable from Access (frontend) to Oracle(backend) Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I am importing csv file to oracle table, i wrote procedure in pl/sql which is having one input parameter which passes the file name to the procedure. I want to give that IN parameter value from ms access (frontend), i am calling the procedure by pass through query, in that i wrote

`call EXT_TABLE()`,  how could i pass IN parameter here.. my plsql code is written below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EXT_TABLE (file_name in varchar2)
AS 
L_QUERY VARCHAR2(1000) := NULL;
L_DROP VARCHAR2(10000) := NULL;

BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE IMPORT_TEST
   ( EMP_ID NUMBER (10)
    )
  ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
    ( TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
      DEFAULT DIRECTORY IMPORT
      ACCESS PARAMETERS 
        ( RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE 
          FIELDS  TERMINATED BY '',''
          MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
        )
          LOCATION ('''||file_name ||''')
        )reject limit unlimited';

L_QUERY:= 'INSERT INTO MPRN SELECT * FROM IMPORT_TEST';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE L_QUERY;
L_DROP := 'drop table IMPORT_TEST ';
execute immediate L_DROP; 
 commit;
END EXT_TABLE;
```

Import is directory, mprn is my file name which is having one column only.
I want that file_name from MS ACCESS that i can pass to the procedure and import can be done

Answer (score 2):

Do not overuse dynamic SQL, try something like:

```
CREATE TABLE IMPORT_TEST(
    EMP_ID NUMBER (10)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
( TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY IMPORT
  ACCESS PARAMETERS 
( RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE 
  FIELDS  TERMINATED BY '',''
  MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
)
  LOCATION ('some_default_filename')
)reject limit unlimited
;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EXT_TABLE(file_name in varchar2)
AS 
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE IMPORT_TEST LOCATION ('''||file_name ||''')';
    INSERT INTO MPRN SELECT * FROM IMPORT_TEST;
END EXT_TABLE;
```

To run this procedure run: `execute EXT_TABLE(file_name => 'my_new_file_name');`

To run this procedure from MS ACCESS you need to use [VBA](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/passthrough3.php)

1. Set up your ODBC connection
2. Create a procedure that will execute Oracle's Stored Procedure.

Comment: how can i pass parameter from MS ACCESS, i am new to ms access and i have to pass IN parameter from MS acess form

Comment: yes, i can use but don't know to how to pass? i am calling procedure via pass through query. It would be a great help if you suggest some way

Comment: Take a look at the link I attached to my post, there is a good paper about executing Oracle's Stored procedures from MS ACCESS.

Comment: While i am trying to pass the parameter, run time error is coming odbc connection failed

Comment: Check for username/password, Check if the listener is up and running.

Comment: username and password is correct, i am trying to call one procedure which is passing any IN OUT parameter then no error is coming and successfully calling that proc. But when I am trying to give parameters as you suggest from the techonthenet.com link it is throwing error. How can i check the listener is up and running??

Comment: Run `lsnrctl status` and add the output to your question.